# JavaScript bind event

Tags: javascript

I want to add the click event to all of the `li element` in my page when I click the `li element`, the content of  `li element` will display in the `input element` , and finally, I want to unbind the click event. I had written two methods to solve this problem, but one of them can not unbind the click event, so I wonder why the click event can not unbind.

```html
<div class="wraper">
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="name" /><button> < </button>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li>Napoleon</li>
      <li>覃小夫</li>
      <li>毛泽东</li>
      <li>戴高乐</li>
      <li>戴高乐</li>
      <li>戴高乐</li>

    </ul>
 </div>
```

Here is my first method to solve the problem, but finally I can't unbind the click event from the `li element` and `button element`.

```js
var select = (function() {
  var obj = {
    Ulshow : false,
    init : function() {
      this.cacheDOM();
      this.bindEvent();
    },
    cacheDOM : function() {
      var doc = document;
      this.ul =doc.querySelector( '.wraper ul' );
      this.button = doc.querySelector( '.wraper button');
      this.input = doc.querySelector( '.wraper input');
    },
    bindEvent : function() {
      this.button.addEventListener( 'click', this.toggleUl.bind( this ), false );
      this.ul.addEventListener( 'click', this.selectLi.bind( this ), false );
    },
    toggleUl : function() {
      var display = this.Ulshow ? 'none' : 'block';
      this.ul.style.display = display;
      this.Ulshow = !this.Ulshow;
    },
    selectLi : function( e ) {
      if ( e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'li' )
        return;
      this.input.value = e.target.innerHTML;
      //hide the ul element
      this.toggleUl();
    },
    unbindEvent : function() {
      this.button.removeEventListener( 'click', this.toggleUl, false );
      this.ul.removeEventListener( 'click', this.selectLi, false );
    }
  };

  obj.init();

  //invoke the unbindEvent function to unbind click event
  //But I found I can not unbind the click event, that's my problem.
  obj.unbindEvent();
  return obj;

})();
```

Here is the second method, I use it to solve my problem(the problem is I can not unbind the click event ), it works, I can unbind the click event from the  `li element` and `button element`.So I wonder the difference between those two methods and I want to know why I can not unbind the click event in my first method.

```js
var selected = (function(){
  var doc = document;
  var DOM = {
    Ulshow : false,
    button : doc.querySelector( '.wraper button' ),
    input : doc.querySelector( '.wraper input' ),
    ul : doc.querySelector( '.wraper ul' )
  }

  function toggleUl() {
    var display = DOM.Ulshow ? 'none' : 'block';
    DOM.ul.style.display = display;
    DOM.Ulshow = !DOM.Ulshow;
  }

  function selectLi( e ) {
    if ( e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'li' )
      return;
    DOM.input.value = e.target.innerHTML;
    toggleUl();
  }

  function bindEvent() {
    DOM.button.addEventListener( 'click', toggleUl, false );
    DOM.ul.addEventListener( 'click', selectLi, false );
  }

  function unbindEvent() {
    DOM.button.removeEventListener( 'click', toggleUl, false );
    DOM.ul.removeEventListener( 'click', selectLi, false );
  }

  function init() {
    bindEvent();
  }

  init();

  return {
    unbindEvent : unbindEvent
  };
})();

//Now I can invoke the selected.unbindEvent function to unbind click event
seleted.unbindEvent();
```

Comment: *"Here are the second method I use to solve my problem, it works"* - So what is your question?

Comment: My problem is I can not unbind the click event in my first method.

Comment: The term "bind" is an unfortunate legacy of the tragic jQuery episode that our community went through. Please use the correct terminology, which is "listen".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The bind() method creates a new function
>   —[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

A function and a bound function are different objects; a new function and reference are returned for each call to `bind`:

```
this.toggleUl !==  this.toggleUl.bind(this)
this.toggleUl.bind(this) !== this.toggleUl.bind(this)
```

Therefore, `obj.unbindEvent`

```
this.button.removeEventListener( 'click', this.toggleUl, false );
```

is referencing a different `EventListener` than was added in `obj.bindEvent`:

```
this.button.addEventListener( 'click', this.toggleUl.bind( this ), false );
```

One way around this would be something like this:

```
var obj = {
  init : function(){
    this.bindCallbacks();
    this.cacheDOM();
    this.bindEvent();
  },
  ...
  bindCallbacks : function(){
    this.toggleUlBound = this.toggleUl.bind(this);
    this.selectLiBound = this.selectLi.bind(this);
  },
  ...
  bindEvent : function(){
    this.button.addEventListener( 'click', this.toggleUlBound, false );
    ...
  }
  unbindEvent : function(){
    this.button.removeEventListener( 'click', this.toggleUlBound, false );
    ...
  }
  ...(etc)...
}
```

**Demo:** ([also as a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c3sq959n/))

```js
var select = (function() {
  var obj = {
    Ulshow : false,
    init : function() {
      this.bindCallbacks();
      this.cacheDOM();
      this.bindEvent();
    },
    bindCallbacks : function(){
      this.toggleUlBound = this.toggleUl.bind(this);
      this.selectLiBound = this.selectLi.bind(this);
    },    
    cacheDOM : function() {
      var doc = document;
      this.ul =doc.querySelector( '.wraper ul' );
      this.button = doc.querySelector( '.wraper button');
      this.input = doc.querySelector( '.wraper input');
    },
    bindEvent : function() {
      this.button.addEventListener( 'click', this.toggleUlBound, false );
      this.ul.addEventListener( 'click', this.selectLiBound, false );
    },
    toggleUl : function() {
      var display = this.Ulshow ? 'none' : 'block';
      this.ul.style.display = display;
      this.Ulshow = !this.Ulshow;
    },
    selectLi : function( e ) {
      if ( e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'li' )
        return;
      this.input.value = e.target.innerHTML;
      //hide the ul element
      this.toggleUl();
    },
    unbindEvent : function() {
      this.button.removeEventListener( 'click', this.toggleUlBound, false );
      this.ul.removeEventListener( 'click', this.selectLiBound, false );
    }
  };
 
  obj.init();
  obj.unbindEvent();
  return obj;

})();
```

```html
<div class="wraper">
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="name" /><button> < </button>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li>Napoleon</li>
      <li>覃小夫</li>
      <li>毛泽东</li>
      <li>戴高乐</li>
      <li>戴高乐</li>
      <li>戴高乐</li>

    </ul>
 </div>
```

A simpler approach would be to do the binding *after* `obj` has been declared, before `obj.init` is called, when you can reference `obj` directly:

```
var obj = { ... };
obj.toggleUl = obj.toggleUl.bind(obj);
obj.selectLi = obj.selectLi.bind(obj);
obj.init();
...
```

On this approach, you should again avoid binding your function in `addEventListener`, which leaves you with an un-captured reference that cannot be re-used in `removeEventListener`.

But the simplest approach is the one you found: don't use object-literal syntax for this job!

Comment: OP, don't mind the down-vote. The false equivalence between the unbound and bound functions in your original approach is definitely the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,I get it now,it is really useful to me.But you know I am a newest of this website,Every time I click the vote button, it will show me that my reputation is less than 15.So, it is a good answer for me,thank you!

Comment: @QinXiaofu I'm glad this explanation was clear! There should be a check-mark beneath the arrows that allows you to choose an answer as resolving your question.